# Google Sheet Formula to Django Logic

Tags: django, google-sheets

I am creating a timesheet for an admin to enter time for users. I am converting this project from Google Sheets to Django. I am stumped to say the least.

I am trying to get the total hours to match with the Google Sheet Formula. But it seems that my Django logic is not adding up.

Here is the Google Sheet Formula:

```
=(IF((MROUND(F6*24,0.25)-MROUND(F5*24,0.25))>=8,((MROUND(F6*24,0.25)-MROUND(F5*24,0.25)))-0.5,((MROUND(F6*24,0.25)-MROUND(F5*24,0.25)))))
```

All cells (F5 and F6) are replaced with Start Time and End Time.

Here is my Django logic.

```
def calculate_total_time(self,start_time, end_time):
        if start_time is not None and end_time is not None:
            start_minutes = start_time.hour * 60 + start_time.minute
            end_minutes = end_time.hour * 60 + end_time.minute

            if end_minutes < start_minutes:
                end_minutes += 24 * 60

            difference_minutes = end_minutes - start_minutes
            total_hours = difference_minutes / 60

            # Calculate the rounded total hours
            rounded_hours = math.floor(total_hours * 4) / 4

            # Adjust for cases where rounding might go over 8 hours
            if rounded_hours >= 8:
                rounded_hours -= 0.5

            return rounded_hours
        else:
            return 0.00
```

Some hours display fine with no issues, but then I have hours like these where the logic does not add up. (Pictures for reference)

**Google Sheet Formula Output:**
[image: Google Sheet Formula]

**Django Logic Output:**
[image: Django Logic Output]

I am trying to get the exact same out that the Google Sheet Formula gives out despite the time entered as it is dynamic. Any help is appreciated.

Edit -
More pictures for reference:

**Google Sheet Formula**
[image: Google Sheet Formula]

**Django Logic**
[image: Django Logic]

Comment: In order to obtain the value of `10.75`, can you provide your values of `start_time` and `end_time` of `def calculate_total_time(self,start_time, end_time):`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and seems to be working. I had the order of rounding wrong.

````
        if start_time is not None and end_time is not None:
            start_minutes = self.mround(start_time.hour * 60 + start_time.minute)
            end_minutes = self.mround(end_time.hour * 60 + end_time.minute)

            if end_minutes < start_minutes:
                end_minutes += 24 * 60

            difference_hours = (end_minutes - start_minutes) / 60

            # Subtract 0.5 if the difference is greater than or equal to 8
            if difference_hours >= 8:
                difference_hours -= 0.5

            return difference_hours
        else:
            return 0.00```
````